# Is there a better way to parse an int in Dart

Tags: dart

This is several questions about int.parse in Dart...

I know that in Dart we can parse a string as an int and catch exceptions using something like:

```dart
try {
  n = int.parse(input.value);
  // etc.
} on FormatException {
  // etc.
}
```

(Which is fine.)

In the documentation, there is the following description of int.parse:

```
int parse(String source, int radix, int onError(String source))
```

When I tried using int.parse with more than one argument, however, I got a complaint from the editor about me using extra arguments. Am I misunderstanding the documentation? And how does one, for example, set the radix?

Comment: `int.parse(input.value, 10)` maybe? What errors do you get?

Comment: The editor complains when int.parse has any more than a single argument...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`Int.parse`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/int.html#parse) uses named, optional parameters.

API:

```
int parse(String source, {int radix, int onError(String source)})
```

The `{ }` around params in the parameter list indicate that these are **optional, named** parameters.
(If you had `[ ]` around params in the parameter list, these would be **optional, positional** parameters)

Example Usage:

```dart
int.parse("123");
int.parse("123", radix:16);
int.parse("123", onError:(source) => print("Source"));
int.parse("123", radix:16, onError:(source) => print(source));
```

Comment: Ah! That explains it perfectly; the mouse-over documentation (that I quoted from) didn't have any curly brackets. Thanks!

Comment: onError is deprecated and shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 59):

In Dart 2, [int.tryParse](https://api.dartlang.org/dev/2.0.0-dev.53.0/dart-core/int/tryParse.html) is available.

It returns null for invalid inputs instead of throwing. You can use it like this:

```
int val = int.tryParse(text) ?? defaultValue;
```

The `onError` parameter in `int.parse` is deprecated.

Comment: It is especially useful when I want to initiate a Text widget but the variable which depends on other variables/calculation may be still Null at the startup time, e.g. child: Text(( derivedNumber * (int.tryParse(myController.userInputVal ) ?? 0)).toString() )),

Comment: What does the ?? mean?

Comment: @ScottF https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54031804/what-are-the-double-question-marks-in-dart