# <input type="number"> generating errors

Tags: dart, angular, angular2-forms

I have the following code snippets

### .html

```
  <input type = "number"
         min = "0"
         max = "120"
         #yearsCtrl = "ngForm"
         [ngFormControl] = "ageForm.controls['yearsCtrl']"
         [(ngModel)] = "age.years"
         id = "years">
```

### .dart

```
class Age
{
  int years = 0;
}

class AgeComponent {
....
  AgeComponent( FormBuilder fb, ModelService
  ageSrvc) {
    ageForm = fb.group( {
      'yearsCtrl': [''],
    } );
    _yearsCtrl = ageForm.controls['yearsCtrl'];

    age = new Age()
  }

...

}
```

My attempts to run the application gives the following errors (partial)

```
>EXCEPTION: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'num' of 'value'. in [AST]
  EXCEPTION: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'num' of 'value'. in [AST]
    (anonymous function)    
  ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'num' of 'value'.
    (anonymous function)    
  ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
    (anonymous function)    
  #0      NumberValueAccessor.writeValue (package:angular2/src/common/forms/directives/number_value_accessor.dart:38:23)
#1      setUpControl (package:angular2/src/common/forms/directives/shared.dart:34:21)
#2      NgFormControl.ngOnChanges (package:angular2/src/common/forms/directives/ng_form_control.dart:111:7)
...
```

It seems as if the type="num" is not being handled. I suspect the age int might be an issue also, in that it is an int but a string is required. The reverse conversion from sting back to int might also be an issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The field needs to be of type `String`. Angular doesn't convert the value.

Similar to [Polymer dart: Data bind integer value to String attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611667/polymer-dart-data-bind-integer-value-to-string-attribute/25611725#25611725)

See also

- [How do I parse a string into a number with Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167496/how-do-i-parse-a-string-into-a-number-with-dart)
- [Is there a better way to parse an int in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289447/is-there-a-better-way-to-parse-an-int-in-dart)

A custom value accessor might help. See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/slVMz6Kgv6KlnUNMDe3o?p=preview) for an example.
The component `Address` implements [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/ControlValueAccessor-interface.html) with `writeValue(v)`, `registerOnChange(fn)`, `registerOnTouched(fn)`

Comment: Why can't a pipe be used for the conversion for the ngModel assignment above? I tried it and it results in errors. I had previously looked at my own post above but couldn't say how I would apply it to angular. I wll take a look at the ControlValueAccessor with writeValue(v)

Comment: I found the use of ControlValueAccessor at [http://plnkr.co/edit/aggee6An1iHfwsqGoE3q?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/aggee6An1iHfwsqGoE3q?p=preview), but would require a port to Dart as some Classes seems different.

Comment: The presence of `#yearsCtrl = "ngForm" or 
         [ngFormControl] = "ageForm.controls['yearsCtrl']"` **ALWAYS** generate the error. Is this a bug or is it that angular2 does not support the number type?