# Pass only the specified optional params to an underlying widget

Tags: flutter, dart

Assume I have a simple function that takes a URL to an svg image and returns a widget:

```
Widget loadImage(String url, { height, width }) {
  // Wrap URL in an SvgPicture and return
  return SvgPicture.network(url)
}
```

I'd like to apply the `width` and `height` params to `SvgPicture` *only* if they are defined. Something like this (though this obviously results in a syntax error):

```
Widget loadImage(String url, { height, width }) {
  // Wrap URL in an SvgPicture and return
  return SvgPicture.network(
    url,
    if(height) height : height, // <-- 
    if(width) width : width, // <-- 
  )
}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you can not pass the parameter conditionally. If you want the `SvgPicture` widget to use its default `height` and `width` (if any), then you can pass `null` to those parameters. In this case, passing `null` to `height` and `width` has exactly the same effect as not using those parameters in the `SvgPicture` at all.

So the most readable way of doing it would be, simply:

```dart
Widget loadImage(String url, {double height, double width}) {
  return SvgPicture.network(
        url,
        height: height,
        width: width
      )
}
```

As a side note, I would recommend always type-annotating parameters in functions, i.e., stating that height and width are `double`.

Comment: If you want to have different default values you could do something like `height: height?? 42` [??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54031804/what-are-the-double-question-marks-in-dart)

Answer (score 2):

If a parameter is optional, it means, it can be null. There for, the receiver function should ensure whether it is null or not.

So, you can simply use

```
Widget loadImage(String url, {double height,double width }) {
  return SvgPicture.network(
        url,
        height: height,
        width: width
      )
}
```

Comment: This would still pass the value `null` if height is not defined. Is there a way to not pass the parameter *at all* (without wrapping everything with if-statements)

Comment: updated. Actually you can pass the height and width as it is.  what problem are you facing?

Comment: In this particular instance, there's no issue (because a height of null is ignored). I was just wondering if there was a way to not pass `null` parameters to the underlying widget at all.

Comment: since it is an optional parameter, you don't need to mind about not passing the value. Optional parameters can take null values by default.