# Dart: What does a question mark (?) after a variable name mean?

Tags: flutter, dart

In Example at https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service/versions/0.4.3/example
there is a code like as follows

```
itemCount: _contacts?.length ?? 0,
```

and I have two question on that,

what is meant by variableName? ( variableName followed by question mark '*?*') e.g in above **_contacts?**

The second question was on two question marks and is at
[What are the ?? double question marks in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54031804/what-are-the-double-question-marks-in-dart)

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#other-operators

Comment: itemCount: _contacts?.length ?? 0. Answer (1) A nullable type by adding a question mark (?) after the type name. For example, a variable _contacts? can contain a value, or it can be null. Answer (2) It is called "Null-aware operators". When ??= is used, to assign a value to an object If that object is null. Or return the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Variable?" is use for null safety.
If _contact has value null then we can't check length of variable or it's throw error.

"??" is used for if condition. It's assign value 0.

[Check Here](https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-dart-2-12-499a6e689c87) for more information.

Comment: [link](https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-dart-2-12-499a6e689c87) check this link for more info

Comment: It should throw error irrespective of question mark is there or not? right?. null value should not have any length. Is there any example where this might be useful.