# The property 'id' can't be unconditionally accesed because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dart-null-safety

I'm trying to use `(profileId: currentUser.id)` in:

```
body: PageView(
    children: <Widget>[
      //Feed(),
      ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('Cerrar sesión'),
        onPressed: logout,
      ),
      SubirPost(currentUser: currentUser),
      EditarPerfil(profileId: currentUser.id),
    ],
    controller: pageController,
    onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  ),
```

but it gives me this error:

```
The property 'id' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').
```

I've already tried with the null check ( like this: `profileId: currentUser!.id` )but when I debug it throws a `Null check operator used on a null value` error

id is declared like this on a user model file:

```
class User {
  final String id;
  final String username;
  final String email;
  final String photoUrl;
  final String displayName;
  final String bio;

User(
  {required this.id,
  required this.username,
  required this.email,
  required this.photoUrl,
  required this.displayName,
  required this.bio});

factory User.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
return User(
  id: doc['id'],
  email: doc['email'],
  username: doc['username'],
  photoUrl: doc['photoUrl'],
  displayName: doc['displayName'],
  bio: doc['bio'],
);}}
```

for profileId is this on another file:

```
 final String profileId;
 EditarPerfil({required this.profileId});
```

I've tried everything I've found

Also, when I try to use `?` on the user model `final String id` I get the error `The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'`

Same with the `final String profileId`

I'm importing the `cloud_firestore`, `firebase_storage` and `google_sign_in` packages.

Comment: Your issue is that the `currentUser` variable is null, not that the `id` is null. When your app first loads, it hasn't got the snapshot from firestore yet, so your user is null. I think your two best options are to either handle the possibility that the user is null and show a loading indicator (or similar), or initialise the `currentUser` as a `User` with empty values (i.e. `id` = ""). The best solution for you will depend on the architecture of your app.

Answer (score 1):

When you are writing `currentUser!.id` then you are ensuring that the currentUser will not be null. so when you the currentUser is `null` then you will get this error : `Null check operator used on a null value`. so you have to make profile id nullable if there is chance that you might get null value upon calling profileId. to do so, just declare id as nullable in `User` class by `String? id`. or another approach I recommend is to use `??` operator ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54031805/14343554)) which is just a condition which represents `if null`. you can use this in the assignment statement of your UserId.
like this :

```
body: PageView(
    children: <Widget>[
      //Feed(),
      ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('Cerrar sesión'),
        onPressed: logout,
      ),
      SubirPost(currentUser: currentUser),
      EditarPerfil(profileId: currentUser.id ?? ''),   // this is a check if the id is not null then it will return the actual value otherwise it will return the empty string.
    ],
    controller: pageController,
    onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  ),
```

Comment: When I include the currentUser.id ?? ' ' it gives me the error "the left operand can't be null, so the right operand is never executed (dead null aware)" so I declare 'String id' as 'String? id' in the User class and it resolves the dead null aware but keeps the error mentioned in the main question.

Comment: If you are getting null value when accessing userId then this `??` operator will replace that with an empty string `''`.  Now Please try to update the question and error message after this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `profileId: currentUser!.id`

Here you are ensuring that currentUser will definitely have a property of id