# createUserWithEmailAndPassword is not workin giving error unexpected null value

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I am facing an error while trying to create a user with an email and password. It is giving an error with the value null.

```
body: Container(
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Email"),
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _email = value;
          });
        },
      ),
      TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Password"),
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _password = value;
          });
        },
        obscureText: true,
      ),
      FlatButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            try {
              final newuser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                  _email, _password); // this is the line for the error
            

              if (newuser != Null) {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/homepage');
              }
            } catch (e) {
              print(e);
            }
          },
          child: Text("Sign Up"))
    ],
  ),
));
```

if some one can help me with this it will be helpful

Comment: can you add the code for the `_auth`?

Comment: didnot understand :(

Comment: the function for the `auth` object

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of the error, you are passing `_email` and `_password` as null to the function. Tried using the `??` in case you have a null variable. For example `Your_Function(_email ?? "", _password ?? "")`

The `??` operator basically means, If the variable is null, use this value. So, if `_email` is `null`, use `""`. For more info, I suggest checking this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54031805/13192893).