# after user is logged out show a diffrent widget flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

this is what shows after login and its working. I need to display the code below whenever a user is not logged in.

```
 Text(
            'Hello,\n ${loggedInUser.firstName}',
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: cyan,
              fontSize: 20,
            ),
          ),
```

i want to show this after logout

```
 Text(
            'Hello,\n please login',
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: cyan,
              fontSize: 20,
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use an ternary operator, something like this

```
return loggedInUser is true
       ? text('Hello,\n ${loggedInUser.firstName}')
       : text('Hello,\n Please Login');
```

In loggedInUser you need to detect is the state of the user is logged or not.

(With a ternary operator you are basically doing an if else operator)

Answer (score 0):

If when the user is logged out, the `loggedInUser` or `loggedInUser.firstName` is `null`, just check it and display the text based on the outcome:

```
Text("Hello,\n" + loggedInUser.firstName ?? "Please Login",
                style: const TextStyle(color: cyan, fontSize: 20))
```

> The ?? double question mark operator means "if null".

See more information about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54031805/11442598).