# Is there a way to assert that user never sends empty text

Tags: string, flutter, dart, textfield, whitespace

I have a textfield, and i save the value to a variable called `message`  message is a nullable field `String? message;` as usual, because it can be null before user enters text right?.. however when checking if it's empty, I've done this

```
if(message != null && message != '') {
  // use the message for a super secret super suspicious act
}
```

but this isn't enough for me coz when user types one space, and sends it, it accepts it as not empty, I tried to tackle this by adding the condition `&& message != ' '` this worked, but now, user can type two spaces and send, I added another condition for two spaces, till I started feeling stupid, I can't handle all the spaces, so I tried using an `.isNotEmpty` property, but it wouldn't let me, because as you know, `message` is nullable, and you can't use `.isNotEmpty` on a field that has the potential of being null, only work around is to add a null check to `message` which I can't do coz I know at some point message is gonna be null, it'll definitely throw an exception,

SO
the big question is, is there a way to make sure user can't send empty messages, or work around my condition by sending a bunch of spaces, how do chat apps like whatsapp and the likes of it make sure you can't send spaces and pass it as a string

Comment: Create a copy of the string, use a RegExp to remove all spaces and check the remaining string's length. If it is 0, it only contained spaces. After the `message != null` check you can safely use `message!` which will work where non nullable values are not allowed.

Comment: thanks a lottt, worked, you could add it as an answer so i can mark it as the answer

Comment: use ?? to add default variable null, example: message ?? ''.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54031804/what-are-the-double-question-marks-in-dart

Answer (score 0):

Try using .trim()

```
String message = "       ";
message.trim();
print(message);
```